# Python CGI Script With Two Submit Buttons

Tags: python, html, cgi

I want to use two submit buttons in python CGI. The CGI script then will take different action later in the same script depending on which button is pressed. This code will show 2 buttons, but not waiting for me to press the button. No chance to execute the following print. How to fix it?

```
import cgi, cgitb
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"  
print "<html>" 
print "<input type='submit' value='Run from Server' name='Submit1' />" 
print "<input type='submit' value='Run from VNC' name='Submit2' />" 
print "</html>" 

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "Submit1" in form:
  print "Button 1..."
elif "Submit2" in form:
  print "Button 2..."
else:
  print "nothing..."
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing your form tags...

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"  
print "<html>" 
print "<form>"
print "<input type='submit' value='Run from Server' name='Submit1' />" 
print "<input type='submit' value='Run from VNC' name='Submit2' />" 
print "</form>"
print "</html>"
```

Comment: I just add the form tags, the code won't execute to  form = cgi.FieldStorage()